# Taking $\log$ to calculate limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Many case, I have seen people taking $\ln$ to calculate certain limits, that is they makes use of the fact $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =\exp(\ln(\lim_{x \to a} (f(x)))$$ **My question** is, what are the conditions for applying this trick?

1. I would imagine that the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ has to be finite in order for this trick to work? Because $\ln(\infty)$ doesn't make sense.
2. I also think the required limit must be non zero as $\ln(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ then getting $x$ close enough to $a$ ensures $f(x)>e^N$ so $\ln f>N$; therefore, $\lim_{x\to a}\ln f(x)=\infty$. The second part is analogous, except it needs more care; for $\ln f\to-\infty$ we require not only that $f\to0$, but that $f>0$ for all $x$ close enough to $a$.

Comment: So the conditions are exactly when it's OK to write $k=\exp(\ln(k))$?

Comment: So whenever the limit lies in $[0, \infty)$ right? The limit can't be negative as then $\ln(-ve)$ doesn't make sense

Comment: The only condition to use this trick is that $f$ must be strictly positive in some neighborhood of the limit point. It has nothing to do with the limit as limits of $0$ and $\infty$ still give the correct limits when taking the exponential.

Comment: So, the answer is quite obvious. But the "fact you have seen people making use of when taking $\ln$ to calculate certain limits" is not that one. Instead, it is $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =\exp(\lim_{x \to a} \ln(f(x))).$$

Comment: @AnneBauval that's the same as $\ln$ is continuous

Comment: No, it is the continuity of $\exp$: $$\lim_ag=\ell\implies\lim_a\exp\circ g=e^\ell,$$ applied to $g=\ln f$ ($\ell\in[-\infty,+\infty]$). And "people you have seen [...]" don't use anything else.